# how to have user to take a photo on mobile - next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, file-upload, frontend

I'm building an object scanning web app using next.js, this is a mobile app.

I am trying to figure out how I can have a "take photo" button, which brings the user to their camera, and they can snap a photo.

Afterwards, I'd like to do some OCR for this photo and extract the texts.

Can someone help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) answer your question?